# Script to parse FROM email address from many text files

Tags: powershell, parsing

I have a collection of 338 .log files. These are just basic text files and no two files have the same file name (but all file names start with "rrm-"). Here is an example of the data they contain:

```
Receiving message #1 : OK (4480 bytes)
From: <djerry@domain.com>
Subject: 2-303-468-02
Message-ID: <PRODVAPP21XvCsLCXPI0035acee@prod.domain.com>
Forwarding to "Some User" <someuser@somedomain.com> : OK
```

I need a script that will open each file one at a time, parse only the "From:" lines (could be 10, could be 1000s) to extract only the email address between the < and > characters, and write the output to a single text file, one email address per line. The rest of the data I don't care about. I also don't care about validating the email addresses. The resulting text file would look like this:

```
djerry@domain.com
bob@domain.com
tom@blah.com
jerry@yada.com
```

I'm not a programmer, I only know how to break things when I try. I don't even know what software / utility I would need to use for this. I'm using a Windows 10 computer. So maybe a Powershell script? Sorry for such a n00b question, I really hate feeling stupid for not knowing how to or being able to google for  a simple solution. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select-String -Pattern '^From: .*?<(.+?)>' -Path rrm-* |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value } > output.txt
```

- `^From: .*?<(.+?)>` is a regex (regular expression) that finds lines that start with `From:` and captures what follows between `<` and `>`.

  - The `.*?` part is to account for an (optional) actual name preceding the `<...>`-enclosed email address, as is common; e.g, `"Dana Jerry" <djerry@domain.com>`. <sup>Thanks, [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician)</sup>
- `$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value` retrieves what was captured.
- `> output.txt` saves the results to a file.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @brian.